# Rolling Month used in a Division Formula to Calculate Monthly Averages

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, I am looking for a way to calculate monthly averages using the number of completed months to date in my dividend in a division formula. So, looking for a way to solve for “x” in the following equation:

**Formula**:
Number of Units) / x = monthly average

**Example Data**:
Jan # of units = 20
...Monthly average = **20**

Feb # of units = 40
...Monthly average is (20+40) / 2 (months) = **30**

Mar # of units = 10
...Monthly average is (20+40+10) /3 (months) = **23**

**Results Table**:
Year    Monthly Average
2022    23

Comment: A tabular data sample would be better.   That said, consider the window function avg() over()   For example avg(units) over ( partition by year(SomeDate) order by SomeDate)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Period] varchar(50),[Units] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2022-01-01',20)
,('2022-02-01',40)
,('2022-03-01',10)
 
Select * 
      ,AvgUnits = avg(Units) over (partition by year(period) order by period)
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Period      Units   AvgUnits
2022-01-01  20      20
2022-02-01  40      30
2022-03-01  10      23
```